# Efficient way of programming in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, performance, optimization, swift2

I would like to know the efficient way to create an app in Swift. Will the number of files (ViewController files) in my Xcode project affect the performance of my app?

For example, for a simple arithmetic calculator app, in the first view I'll display 4 buttons for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. If I click on a button, then it will open a new view to enter the data and process it.

So, now my question is, should I create 4 different viewControllers or should I use only one viewController to perform all the 4 operations?
Which one would be the efficient way?

Comment: Make your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If the four controllers differ insignificantly, don't make four controllers. Unless you're programming game loops or device drivers, you should always make programmer speed more important than program speed.

Comment: Don't think about efficiency. Think about code readability, clarity and most importantly user experience. A calculator app that keeps popping up views for data entry sounds terrible

Comment: In my suggestion use single view Controller , if you need additional use extension ,

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Actually I am not working on a calculator app now. I just used it for an example. I am currently working on a project, which uses http request and response. The request and response for 3 processes are same. I am using table view controller to display the response. The only thing is I need to show different data for each process. So, I am in dilemma whether I need to create 3 viewControllers or to use 1 viewController to show corresponding data using if..else..

Comment: Thank you @Anbu.Karthik for your suggestion. I'll make a note of it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your question isn't about Swift, it is about UIKit.

Second, you are looking at the problem the wrong way. Different view controllers will control different views. Switching from one view to another is a user action. Do you want the user to switch from one view to another, or do you want them to use one view all the time without switching?

If there is one view displaying different things, it's one view controller. If it's several views displaying different things, it's several view controllers. And I can assure you that the number of view controllers is *not* what makes your app fast or slow.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. My question is not related with switching of views. I mentioned that calculator app for an example.But I got the answer from this statement **the number of view controllers is not what makes your app fast or slow**